# Use of a slice and a boolean index in the same iloc statement

Tags: python, pandas

"Python for data analysis" (ch5) uses a double selection:

```
data.iloc[:,:3][data.three>5]
```

There is no explanation of the logic behind this statement. How should it be understood?

Is it a selection over a previous selection, i.e. `data.iloc[:,:3]` first selects all lines and first three columns, then `[data.three>5]` reduces this selection to all lines for which the values in column 'three' is greater than 5 ?

I saw also the following expression:

```
df[['CoCode','Doc_Type','Doc_Nr','Amount_LC']][df['Amount_LC']>1000000000]
```

I am a bit lost. It looks like `loc` and `iloc` can be used with double selection, i.e `df.loc[][]` what is the logic of the second `[]`? What goes in the first one, and in the second ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two separate selections are being applied here to dataframe `data`:

1) `data.iloc[:,:3]` is selecting all rows, and all columns up to (but not including) column index 3, thus column indices 0, 1 and 2

2) The dataframe `data` is being limited to all rows where column `three` contains values greater than 5

The output of these two selections is independent of ordering, therefore:

`data.iloc[:,:3][data.three>5] == data[data.three>5].iloc[:,:3]` will return a dataframe populated with `True`

Note that you are not using double selection here (as you call it), but rather you are querying specific rows and columns in your first selection, while your second selection is merely a filter applied to the dataframe returned by your first selection.

Effectively, you are using `.iloc()` to select specific index locations (or slices) from the dataframe, while `.loc()` allows to select specific locations based on column and row labels.

Finally, when filtering your dataframe with something like `data[data.three>5]`, you can read this as "Return rows in dataframe `data` where the column `three` of that row has a value greater than 5".

Comment: 'data.iloc[:,:3][data.three>5] == data[data.three>5].iloc[:,:3]' explains it all. when you say "two separate selections are being applied", is it the max, or can you a third, a fourth... selection ?

Comment: In terms of selecting rows and/or columns, I would say that you should limit that to a single slice/query. In terms of applying multiple filters, you can definitely do so, for example: `data[(data['first']>5) & (data['third']<3) & (data['second']==2)]`

Answer (score 0):

iloc and loc take 2 parameters , columns and rows.

```
data.iloc[<row selection> , <column selection>]
```

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it a selection over a previous selection, i.e. data.iloc[:,:3] first selects all lines and first three columns, then [data.three>5] reduces this selection to all lines for which the values in column 'three' is greater than 5 ?

Yes, **@rahlf23** has great explanation.

> It looks like loc and iloc can be used with double selection, i.e df.loc[][] what is the logic of the second []? What goes in the first one, and in the second ?

Even you can make triple or more selection of **rows**.
Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4,5], 'b':[6,7,8,9,10], 'c': [11,12,13,14,15]})

# It will give you first 3 rows of column a and b
df.loc[:,:2][:4][:3]

# It will give you {'a':[2,3], 'b':[7,8]}
df.iloc[:,:2][df.a*7 > df.c][:2]

# It will give you error, you can't slice more on columns
df.iloc[:,:2][:3,:1]
```